# Handlebars TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper, zurb-ink

I created a custom handlebars helper and I'm getting the following error when I do not define value for parameters.

```
module.exports = function(src, color, classatr, options) {

    if (typeof src === 'undefined') src = '';
    if (typeof color === 'undefined') color = '';
    if (typeof classatr === 'undefined') classatr = '';

    var bg = '<table class="'+ classatr +'" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">\
      <tr>\
        <td background="'+ src +'" bgcolor="'+ color +'" valign="top">\
          <!--[if gte mso 9]>\
          <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="mso-width-percent:1000;">\
            <v:fill type="tile" src="'+ src +'" color="#'+ color +'" />\
            <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">\
          <![endif]-->\
          <div>'
          + options.fn(this) +
          '</div>\
          <!--[if gte mso 9]>\
            </v:textbox>\
          </v:rect>\
          <![endif]-->\
        </td>\
      </tr>\
    </table>';

    return bg;
}
```

This works if I define all three parameters as such:

```
{{#bg-img 'assets/img/hero-header.jpg' '000000' 'my-class'}}
    <container>
        <row>
            <columns>
            </columns>
        </row>
    </container>
{{/bg-img}}
```

If I do not define a parameter console shows "Handlebars TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined".

```
{{#bg-img }}
    <container>
        <row>
            <columns>
            </columns>
        </row>
    </container>
{{/bg-img}}
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Update: Also checked with "null" as suggested below but still same error.

```
if (typeof src === 'undefined' || src === null) src = '';
if (typeof color === 'undefined' || color === null) color = '';
if (typeof classatr === 'undefined' || classatr === null) classatr = '';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `null` where you don't wanna provide any parameter. so, the following code should work :

```
{{#bg-img null null null}}
    <container>
        <row>
            <columns>
            </columns>
        </row>
    </container>
{{/bg-img}}
```

Comment: Is there a way around not having to put "null"

Comment: I don't think there is. because by using `null` you are telling the function that the parameter exists (means its defined) even tho it doesn't contain any value. which you can't do with anything else (ie. 'undefined'). so `null` is the best possible way to get around w/o actually providing any param.

Comment: {{#bg-img '' '' ''}} that does the trick. Thanks for the help. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't declare optional parameters in your functions signature. Handlebars puts a hash object in the supplied options object passed to your function. Through the hash object you can access all the supplied parameters. Please refer to the "Hash Arguments" section in the [Block Helpers Documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html).

```
module.exports = function(options) {

var src = options.hash.src;
var color = options.hash.color;
var classatr = options.hash.classatr;
if (typeof src === 'undefined') src = '';
if (typeof color === 'undefined') color = '';
if (typeof classatr === 'undefined') classatr = '';
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to check your attributes with null, not undefined?

Comment: Checked with null and undefined still same error.

Still spits out same typeerror.